# Implementing Parser Functor

Tags: haskell

Working on Brent Yorgey's 2013 UPenn [class](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/10-applicative.pdf) homework, the following `newtype` exists:

`newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }`

I'm trying to implement `Parser` as a `Functor`.

Given the following `first` function to help with this problem:

```
first :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
first f (a, c) = (f a, c)
```

I tried the following:

```
instance Functor (Parser) where
  fmap g (Parser f)  = Parser $ fmap (first g) (f . g)
```

However, that doesn't work.

As I understand, `f`'s type is `String -> Maybe (a, String)`. So, I don't know how to `apply` a `String` to `f` in order to get `Maybe (a, String)`.

Once I get a `Maybe (a, String)`, I believe that I can simply run `fmap (first g) ...` where `...` represents the `Maybe`.

Please give me a hint to understand how to get the `Maybe (a, String)`.

Since `f` is owed a `String` to give a type of `Maybe (a, String)`, I don't know where to find that `String` argument.

Comment: You're close. You only want to apply `g` once and you want to do it in a way that changes the results of the `f` application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing great.

If I just make a type synonym it might be clearer

```
type M a = Maybe (a,String)
```

You're right that you can use

```
fmap (first g) :: Maybe (a, String) -> Maybe (b,String)
--             :: M a -> M b
```

and combine it with

```
f :: String -> Maybe (a,String)
--   String -> M a
```

You just need to compose `String -> M a` with `M a -> M b` to get `String -> M b`:

```
instance Functor (Parser) where
  fmap g (Parser f)  = Parser $ fmap (first g) . f
```

---

You asked if you could get a String from somewhere. Lambda will do that for you: `\xs ->` can be read "give me a String `xs`...", and you could apply `f` to that String to get something of type `Maybe (a,String)`. So you could also write:

```
instance Functor (Parser) where
  fmap g (Parser f)  = Parser $ \xs -> fmap (first g) (f xs)
```

Answer (score -1):

To apply g on a Parser f, i.e. composite g and f. However, as g is a general function,and f returns Maybe(a,String), we need to convert g to

```
Maybe(a,String)->d
```

. Given `first::(a->b)->(a,c)->(b,c)`
,then

```
first.Maybe :: Maybe(a->b,a->b)->Maybe(a,String)->Maybe(b,String)
first.Maybe :: (a->b)->Maybe(a,String)->Maybe(b,String)
first.Maybe g ::  Maybe(a,String)->Maybe(b,String)
```

so

```
instance Functor Parser where
  fmap g f = Parser $ fmap (first.Maybe g) . f
```