# Implement `Applicative Parser`'s Apply Function

Tags: parsing, haskell

From Brent Yorgey's 2013 Penn [class](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/10-applicative.pdf), after getting help on defining a [Functor Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27673320/409976), I'm attempting to make an `Applicative Parser`:

```
--p1 <*> p2 represents the parser which first runs p1 (which will
--consume some input and produce a function), then passes the
--remaining input to p2 (which consumes more input and produces
--some value), then returns the result of applying the function to the
--value
```

Here's my attempt:

```
instance Applicative (Parser) where
  pure x                    = Parser $ \_ -> Just (x, [])
  (Parser f) <*> (Parser g) = case (\ys -> f ys) of Nothing      -> Parser Nothing
                                                    Just (_, xs) -> Parser $ g xs
```

However, I'm getting compile-time errors on the `apply (<*>)` definition.

Intuitively, I believe that using `<*>` achieves `AND` functionality.

If I have a parser for `foo` and a parser for `bar`, then I should be able to use `apply <*>` to say: `foo` followed by `bar`. In other words, input of `foobar` should successfully match, whereas `foobip` would not. It would fail on the second parser.

However, I believe that the types are:

`Parser (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b`

So, that makes me think that my intuition is not entirely correct.

Please give me a **tip** to guide me towards understanding how to implement `apply`.

Comment: Here's a leading question: if p1 
"will consume some input and produce a function" and you need "the result of applying the function", where in your code can you find that function? Where can you find its application?

Comment: Your types are right. You need `Parser b`, so you should return something of the same _form_ as `pure x`; you should write `Parser $ \s -> ` at the start. Because `Parser f :: Parser (a->b)` You have `f:: String -> Maybe (a->b,String)`, so you can apply `f` to a string to get a `Maybe (a->b,String)` which you can pattern match on. If that's `Just (someFunction,remainingInput)` then you could apply `g` to the `remainingInput` to get something of type `Maybe (a,String)`, and if you get a result from that like `Just (aValue,finalRemainingInput)` you could apply `someFunction` to `aValue`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is predicated on a misunderstanding of what a `Parser` is. Don't worry, virtually everybody makes this mistake.

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }
```

Lets break down what this means.

```
String -> Maybe (a, String)
[1]       [2]   [3] [4]
```

[1]: I take a string and return `Maybe (a, String)`

[2]: I might not succeed in parsing the input into the desired datatype

[3]: The desired type I am parsing the String *into*

[4]: Remaining input after having consumed the amount of data required to parse `a`

`Parser` is a *function* of text input to *Maybe* a tuple of a value and the rest of the text. `Parser` is emphatically *not* a tuple, otherwise you wouldn't have a parser. Just data in a tuple.

I'm not going to tell you how to implement `<*>` and nobody else should either as it would deprive you of the experience.

However, I'll give you `pure` so you understand the basic pattern:

```
 pure a = Parser (\s -> Just (a, s))
```

See? It's a function of s -> Maybe (a, s). I intentionally mimicked the type variables in my terms to make it more obvious.

Comment: ...and the key difference with this definition of pure is that the input it is given (`s`) is the same as the remaining input it returns, so it leaves the input stream alone rather than terminating the parse run by throwing away the rest of the input (`_`) and returning `[]` as the remaining input.