# Function composition versus noob lambdas clashing together inside an fmap functor instance using Parsers

Tags: haskell

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }

first :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
first f (a, c) = (f a, c)

inParser f = Parser . f . runParser

-- My solution
instance Functor Parser where
  fmap g (Parser f) = Parser (\xs -> fmap (first g) (f xs))


-- Second solution
instance Functor Parser where
  fmap = inParser . fmap . fmap . first
```

There are two fmap definitions above, how are they equivalent?

Can you explain how second solution works?

Same question asked here: [Implementing Parser Functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673320/implementing-parser-functor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution works with the `fmap` instance of `Maybe` and I think you understand it right?

The second one is hard to get yeah - so maybe it's worth to reintroduce some *points* and `(`..`)`?

First let's add a signature to `inParser`:

```
inParser :: ((String -> Maybe (a, String)) -> 
               (String -> Maybe(b, String))) 
            -> Parser a -> Parser b
```

as you can see this really just unwraps/wraps the kernel of the problem ;) - using this you can concentrate on dealing just with `String -> Maybe (a,String)`

the other parts (`fmap`, `first`) are there for the same reason: they *unwrap* stuff till you can get at the `a` to act on it:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
fmap f p 
{ def }
= inParser (fmap . fmap $ first f) $ p
{ def inParser }
= Parser . (fmap . fmap $ first f) . runParser $ p
```

remember `runParser p` takes an `String` and returns a `Maybe (a, String)`

`first f` is `(a,c) -> (b,c)` or here `(a,String) -> (b,String)` and the first `fmap` there is using the `Maybe`-functor instance to translate this into a `Maybe (a,String) -> Maybe (b,String)`.

the next `fmap` will translate the `String -> Maybe (a, String)` into a `String -> Maybe (b, String)` by using the `(->) String` functor-instance.

Finally `Parser` just wraps it up again.

I hope this helps a bit.

---

having said that, your version is *arguably* more readable and while the second one is a nice brain-teaser and seems to be more terse/Haskelly I would prefer the first version ;)

Answer (score 1):

A useful way to decipher point-free code such as

```
fmap = inParser . fmap . fmap . first
```

is to forget what the code is actually doing, and just look at the types.

We start with a function of type

```
fun :: a -> b
```

assuming that is the argument our defined `fmap` operates on . We apply `first`, changing its type to

```
first $ fun :: (a, String) -> (b, String)
```

Above, I guessed the second component was `String` by looking at the parser's type. Then we apply `fmap`... since there's a `Maybe` in the parser's definition we guess it must be done at that type:

```
fmap . first $ fun :: Maybe (a, String) -> Maybe (b, String)
```

Another `fmap`. Now we guess it must be at the `(->) String` functor:

```
fmap . fmap . first $ fun :: (String -> Maybe (a, String)) -> 
                             (String -> Maybe (b, String))
```

Finally, `inParser` wraps inside the `newtype`:

```
inParser . fmap . fmap . first $ fun :: Parser a -> Parser b
```

Hence:

```
inParser . fmap . fmap . first :: (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
```

Voila.

Note how we needed to guess a few things by looking to the parser's type. This makes the code hard to read unless you somehow know what is your final destination type.

For this, I would not recommend using a pointfree style in this case.